# REST API for SPARQL in Django (Python)?

Tags: python, reactjs, django-rest-framework, sparql, rdflib

### Introduction

The challenge I bring to you today is: To implement a **Real Rime REST API** (`GET`, `POST`, `PUT`, `DELETE`, etc) to **query** and **update** any **SPARQL** endpoint using the **Django REST Framework** for a frontend application (I am using **React**) to request and use the serialized data provided by the **REST API**.

Please note that I'm using Django because I would like to implement **Web** AND **Mobile** applications in the future, but for now I will just implement it on a **React Web** application.

### Specifications

The **REST API** should be able to:

- Perform (read or update) queries to a **SPARQL** endpoint via **HTTP** requests.
- Serialize the response to a **JSON** RDF standarized table, or an **RDF Graph**, depending on the **HTTP** response.
- Store the serialized response in a **Python** object.
- Provide an endpoint with the serialized response to a frontend application such as React).
- Handle incoming requests from the frontend application, *"translate"* and execute as a **SPARQL** query.
- Send back the response to the frontend application's request.

**ALL OF THIS** while performing all queries and updates **In Real Time**.

### What I mean with a *Real Time API*:

1. A **SPARQL** query is executed from the **REST API** to a **SPARQL** endpoint via an **HTTP** request.
2. The **REST API** reads the **HTTP** response generated from the request.
3. The **REST API** serializes the response to the corresponding format.
4. This serialized response is stored locally in a **Python** object for future use.

(Note: All the triples from the **SPARQL** endpoint in the query now exist both in the **SPARQL** endpoint as well as in a **Python** object, and are consistent both locally and remotely.)

1. The triples are then (hypothetically) modified or updated (Either locally or remotely).
2. Now the **local** triples are **out of synch** with the **remote** triples.
3. The **REST API** now becomes *aware* of this update (maybe through **Listener/Observer** objects?).
4. The **REST API** then automatically **synchs** the triples, either through an update query request (if the changes were made locally) or by updating the **Python** object with the response from a query request (if the update was made remotely).
5. Finally, both (the **SPARQL** endpoint and the **Python** object) should share the latest updated triples and, therefore, be in **synch**.

### Previous Attempts

I have currently been able to query a **SPARQL** endpoint using the **`SPARQLWrapper`** package (for executing the queries), and the `RDFLib` and `JSON` packages for serializing and instantiating **Python** objects from the response, like this:

```
import json

from rdflib import RDFS, Graph

from SPARQLWrapper import GET, JSON, JSONLD, POST, TURTLE, SPARQLWrapper


class Store(object):
    def __init__(self, query_endpoint, update_endpoint=None):
        self.query_endpoint = query_endpoint
        self.update_endpoint = update_endpoint
        self.sparql = SPARQLWrapper(query_endpoint, update_endpoint)

    def graph_query(self, query: str, format=JSONLD, only_conneg=True):
        results = self.query(query, format, only_conneg) 
        results_bytes = results.serialize(format=format)
        results_json = results_bytes.decode('utf8').replace("'", '"')
        data = json.loads(results_json)
        return data

    def query(self, query: str, format=JSON, only_conneg=True):
        self.sparql.resetQuery()
        self.sparql.setMethod(GET)
        self.sparql.setOnlyConneg(only_conneg)
        self.sparql.setQuery(query)
        self.sparql.setReturnFormat(format)
        return self.sparql.queryAndConvert()

    def update_query(self, query: str, only_conneg=True):
        self.sparql.resetQuery()
        self.sparql.setMethod(POST)
        self.sparql.setOnlyConneg(only_conneg)
        self.sparql.setQuery(query)
        self.sparql.query()


store = Store('http://www.example.com/sparql/Example')
print(store.query("""SELECT ?s WHERE {?s ?p ?o} LIMIT 1"""))
print(store.graph_query("""DESCRIBE <http://www.example.com/sparql/Example/>"""))
```

### The Challenge

The previous code solves can already:

- ***Perform (read or update) queries to a SPARQL endpoint via HTTP requests***
- **Serialize the response to a JSON RDF standarized table, or an RDF Graph, depending on the HTTP response**
- **Store the serialized response in a Python object.**

But still fails to implement these other aspects:

- Provide an endpoint with the serialized response to a frontend application such as React).
  Handle incoming requests from the frontend application, "translate" and execute as a SPARQL query.**
- **Send back the response to the frontend application's request.**

And last, but not least, it fails **completely** to implement the **real time** aspect of this challenge.

### The Questions:

- How would you implement this?
- Is this really the best approach?
- Can the already working code be optimized?
- Is there something that already does this?

### Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry but I don't know anything much about Django so can't answer here with Django specifics.

However, I can say this: SPARQL has a specification for HTTP interactions (https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-protocol/) and it tells you to use `sparql?query=...` & `sparql?update...` style URIs for querying a store, so why define a new way of doing things with `store.query` & `store.graph_query` etc?

Is there a Django-specific reason?

You can already pose questions to a SPARQL Endpoint using React or whatever you want right now, just as it is.

You said what is missing is to "Provide an endpoint with the serialized response" but the SPARQL responses are this! SPARQL query response formats are defined in the spec (e.g. JSON: https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-results-json/) and SPARQLWrapper knows how to parse them into Python objects. Other language libraries, like rdflib.js in JavaScript also know.

See YASGUI (https://triply.cc/docs/yasgui) for a stand-alone JS SPARQL client.